# Permission denied installing packages when build docker image based on logstash

Tags: docker, dockerfile, logstash

I am working on a project on a logstash docker image and i want to add a layer to a Dockerfile to install python3.
The Dockerfile is as follows :

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.3.2
RUN yum -y install python3
```

but when i run `docker build .` , i get the error

```
**Step 2/2 : RUN yum -y install python3
 ---> Running in 695de9a8778c
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Requirename'
You need to be root to perform this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install python3' returned a non-zero code: 1**
```

what is the solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the logstash container runs as user which is not root and is named logstash, but only root (or a sudoer) can install packages.
The best solution in my opinion is to put `USER root` in docker file before the installation lines, in order to run the following lines as root.
then install everything.
and finally after installing everything add the line `USER logstash` to return everything to the way they were before.

example of the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.3.2
USER root
RUN 'yum update -y && yum -y install python3'
USER logstash
```